# Do you have information out there on the process of transitioning from a different data catalog to IBM's?

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

I'm looking for general information on how the process of transitioning to WKC (on cloud and/or on-prem) will be for Collibra data catalog customers, for example.  Specifically if it's an easy transition, and/or if there are services dedicated to helping with transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, business glossary terms can be imported via csv file, but information assets (data assets, connections) will need to be added or discovered via the application or apis.

Here's the documentation on importing business terms for WKC:
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/governance/dmg17.html?audience=wdp&context=wdp